# "class not found" while updating Laravel project packages

Tags: php, laravel

When run `composer update` in Laravel project, I get the error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information  
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file  
Nothing to install or update  
Generating optimized autoload files  
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump  
> @php artisan package:discover

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

Class 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider' not   
found                                                                        

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event
returned with error code 1
```

I've tried to add to `composer.json`:

`"extra": { "laravel": { "dont-discover": [ "laravel/dusk" ] } }`

And clear the cache:

```
cd bootstrap/cache/
rm -rf *.php
```

Nothing helped.

**`composer.json`**:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy": "^1.1",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.21",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-ckeditor": "^4.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "laravel/homestead": "^7.20",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: share your `composer.json` file please!

Comment: + try @ https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24383

Comment: @Iftikharuddin provided composer.json file

Comment: Just for testing try removing NunoMaduro entry from composer, delete vendor folder and do composer install. This is to check if there is something wrong with the package's internal dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package is installed correctly and the missing class actually exists, try running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: What happens if you run `composer remove nunomaduro/collision` and then `composer require nunomaduro/collision --dev` again?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your `vendor` folder is corrupted. Just reinstall your packages again:

```
rm -rf vendor
rm composer.lock
composer install
```

Comment: followed your instruction, but get the same error :(

Comment: you are the life saviour